# Function to repeat number N times

Tags: functions, contest-math

I am not a math person, but is it possible to repeat one number N times without programming langs or programs? If yes, which type of function can I use to do it? For example: number `2` repeat 3 times and get `222`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this function:

$$f(x,n)=10^{n-1} \times x + 10^{n-2} \times x + 10^{n-3} \times x +...+ 10^{2} \times x + 10^1 \times x + 10^0 \times x$$ i.e.
$$f(x,n)=\left(\frac{10^n-1}{9}\right)\cdot x$$ Where $x$ is the digit you want to repeat and $n$ is the number of times you want to repeat.

**Note:** This formula is valid for $1\le x\le 9$.

Answer (score 1):

You could multiply it by $111 = \dfrac{10^{3} - 1}{10-1}$

Adjust the $3$ if you want a different number of repeats and the $10$s if your original number has more digits.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $10^3$ and not $10^{3+1}$?

Comment: @Aniket perhaps it should

Answer (score 1):

Very short answer:
$$f(x,n)=x\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} 10^k$$

**Edit** someone has posted an even shorter answer already, leaving it here since this works as well! :-)

Comment: Yep, thank you so much, it's works perfect, but I select another answer. However, thanks!

Comment: @BobNapkin, You're welcome! The other answer is just brilliant! :)

Comment: I do not see the difference, they are the same function, but yours is written compactly

Comment: @SomeGuy, look at the time of posting - maybe it was posted as I was typing! I don't know how it is now, but things were a bit rusty back then - new answers won't appear unless we refresh the page!

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ has two digits, you want 
$$f(x,n)=\left(\frac{100^n-1}{99}\right)x$$